# How to set/determine the cipher suite in Xamarin?

Tags: ssl, xamarin, mono

This seems like such a simple question but I can't seem to find a straight answer. I just want to know what SSL/TLS cipher suites are available in Xamarin/mono. This question has been [asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341014/in-mono-how-to-control-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suite), but its answer points to a link that is seven years old at this point. The analogous entry in the [mono source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/CipherSuiteFactory.cs), is similarly anachronistic. Have they really not updated their available cipher suites in five (at least) years?! No DHE?!

I would be shocked if I weren't missing something pretty basic. Please help me out!

Comment: Xamarin is working on TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2, but I don't know the cipher suites. You can follow the commits here: https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/work-newtls

Comment: Based on this [README](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/work-newtls/mcs/class/Mono.Security.Providers/README.md), it appears the idea is to provide a platform abstraction.

Comment: Thanks @jstedfast for the response. I was going to look through the source, but this particular issue wasn't important enough and I really didn't have the time. And frankly, I really thought that "what type of cipher suites do you offer?" was the type of question whose answer should be easy to find in documentation.

Comment: It's probably just something very few people actually care about.

Answer (score 0):

So reading [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/40646/#Comment_40646) from Jan 2014 by a Xamarin spokesperson, I think that the answer is yes, Xamarin is stuck in 2008.

Feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.